# Dynamic SQL - iterate through table columns and get percent of populated fields

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to use the following dynamic SQL to iterate through columns in a table and get the percent pop for each field in the table.  Here is the script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PercentPop] (
[Field Name] VARCHAR(255),
[Percent Pop] DECIMAL(6, 3)
)

DECLARE @rowCount as INT
SET @rowCount = (SELECT MAX([Ordinal_Position]) FROM information_schema.columns)

DECLARE @i as INT
SET @i = 1

DECLARE @Column as varchar(255)
DECLARE @Percent as DECIMAL(6, 3)

WHILE @i <= @rowCount
BEGIN
   SET @Column = (SELECT [Column_name] FROM information_schema.columns 
   WHERE [table_name] = 'myTable' AND [Ordinal_Position] = @i)

   SET @Percent = (SELECT 100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN @Column <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) 
   AS ColumnPercent FROM myTable)

   INSERT INTO [dbo].[PercentPop] VALUES (@Column, @Percent)

  SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

The result of this script produces the field names correctly, but each of the percentages are 100%.  I'm wondering if something isn't iterating correctly, because the first field is 100% populated, but I know subsequent fields are not.

Comment: You're not actually using dynamic sql, but rather checking if the column name is blank. Since the column name isn't blank,  they all come back with 100%.

Comment: you're right...it seems so obvious now.  its only checking the value of the @Column variable, not the actual column itself.